# Order files by multiple criteria using lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda

```
Full_Movie_da-DK_11-31-17.tsv
Full_Movie_de-AT_11-31-17.tsv
Full_Movie_de-CH_11-31-17.tsv
Full_Movie_de-DE_11-31-17.tsv
Full_TvEpisode_da-DK_11-31-17.tsv
Full_TvEpisode_de-AT_11-31-17.tsv
Full_TvEpisode_de-CH_11-31-17.tsv
Full_TvEpisode_de-DE_11-31-17.tsv
Full_TvSeason_da-DK_11-31-17.tsv
Full_TvSeason_de-AT_11-31-17.tsv
Full_TvSeason_de-CH_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_Movie_da-DK_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_Movie_de-AT_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_Movie_de-CH_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_Movie_de-DE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_TvEpisode_da-DK_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_TvEpisode_de-AT_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_TvEpisode_de-CH_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_TvEpisode_de-DE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_TvSeason_da-DK_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_TvSeason_de-AT_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
Increment_TvSeason_de-CH_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv
```

I want to sort it in the following order:

1. Increment before Full
2. Movie before TvSeason before TvEpisode

How would I do this sort? So far I had:

```
>>> files = ['Full_Movie_da-DK_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_de-AT_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_de-CH_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_de-DE_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_en-AU_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_en-CA_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_en-GB_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_en-IE_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_en-NZ_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_en-US_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_es-ES_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_es-MX_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_fi-FI_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_fr-BE_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_fr-CA_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_Movie_fr-CA_11-31-17.tsv.bz2', 'Full_TvEpisode_da-DK_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_de-AT_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_de-CH_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_de-DE_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_en-AU_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_en-CA_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_en-GB_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_en-IE_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_en-NZ_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_en-US_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_es-ES_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_es-MX_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_fi-FI_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvEpisode_fr-BE_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_da-DK_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_de-AT_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_de-CH_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_de-DE_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_en-AU_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_en-CA_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_en-GB_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_en-IE_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_en-NZ_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_en-US_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_es-ES_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_es-MX_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_fi-FI_11-31-17.tsv', 'Full_TvSeason_fr-BE_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_da-DK_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_de-AT_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_de-CH_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_de-DE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_en-AU_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_en-CA_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_en-GB_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_en-IE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_en-NZ_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_en-US_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_es-ES_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_es-MX_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_fi-FI_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_Movie_fr-BE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_da-DK_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_de-AT_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_de-CH_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_de-DE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_en-AU_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_en-CA_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_en-GB_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_en-IE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_en-NZ_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_en-US_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_es-ES_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_es-MX_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_fi-FI_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvEpisode_fr-BE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_da-DK_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_de-AT_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_de-CH_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_de-DE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_en-AU_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_en-CA_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_en-GB_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_en-IE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_en-NZ_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_en-US_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_es-ES_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_es-MX_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_fi-FI_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv', 'Increment_TvSeason_fr-BE_2016-02-19_11-48-26_2016-02-20_11-31-17.tsv']

>>> sorted(files, key= lambda x: ('Increment' in x, 'Movie' in x, 'TvSeason' in x, 'TvEpisode' in x))
```

But this seems to sort it in the reverse order of how I want it. What would be the correct syntax here?

Comment: *"a bit off"*?! I'd expect better from your rep.

Comment: Could you provide a better description of "a bit off" for future readers?

Comment: You need a `'` after `'TvSeason`.

Comment: @wrkyle thank you for the feedback. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because lambda function sorts False (0) before True (1) you would need to make sure that the parameter is evaluated to `False` for it to appear first. This, the correct expression would be:

```
sorted(files, key=lambda x: (
                   ('Increment' not in x),
                   ('Movie' not in x),
                   ('TvSeason' not in x), 
                   ('TvEpisode' not in x)
               )
      )
```